# Replace slashes in this json format

Tags: json

```
{
    "id": "81",
    "user_id": "107",
    "comment": "hi, \"i am new to thyis group please help me\"",
    "group_id": "26",
    "readArr": "",
    "first_name": "test",
    "name": "Red Cube Group2"
},
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: remove the backslashes from comment it is encoded in json

Comment: Please post the code you wrote to try to solve your problem

Comment: i only want to send the data in json format without these backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send quotes within a JSON string without escaping the quotes. Otherwise this would result in an invalid JSON format. What exactly is your goal? Where do you want to replace the slashes? Backend? Frontend? PHP?